# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un while que contenga 3 variables?

Tags: c++

```
void main(void) {
ANSEL=00000000; TRISA=1; PORTA=1; TRISB=0; PORTB=0;
while(1){ 
while(RA0==0,RA1==0,RA2==0){ RB0==0; __delay_ms(0); RB0==0; } 
while(RA0==0,RA1==0,RA2==1){ RB0==1; __delay_ms(1); RB0==0; } 
while(RA0==0,RA1==1,RA2==0){ RB0==1; __delay_ms(2); RB0==0; } 
while(RA0==0,RA1==1,RA2==1){ RB0==1; __delay_ms(3); RB0==0; }
while(RA0==1,RA1==0,RA2==0){ RB0==1; __delay_ms(4); RB0==0; }
while(RA0==1,RA1==0,RA2==1){ RB0==1; __delay_ms(5); RB0==0; }
while(RA0==1,RA1==1,RA2==0){ RB0==1; __delay_ms(6); RB0==0; }
while(RA0==1,RA1==1,RA2==1){ RB0==1; __delay_ms(7); RB0==0; }
}
return;
}
```

lo que pasa es que me salta un error de corto circuito

Answer (score 3):

> while(RA0==0,RA1==0,RA2==0)

`while` evalúa **una única condición** ... y tu le estás pasando tres, luego es totalmente normal que no funcione.

Tienes que conseguir que esas tres variables den un único resultado ¿Y cómo se consigue eso? Pues con lógica booleana (AND, OR, XOR).

Es decir, para que el bucle se repita si se cumplen las 3 condiciones a la vez:

```
while(RA0==0 && RA1==0 && RA2==0)
```

Aunque fíjate que el contenido del bucle no modifica las variables evaluadas... así que salvo que éstas cambien en otro hilo es perfectamente probable que acabes entrando en un bucle sin fin

Answer (score 3):

> ¿Cómo puedo hacer un while (C++) que contenga 3 variables?

Un `while` puede contener programas enteros, no sólo tres variables. En realidad lo que quieres saber es: "*¿Cómo hacer para que la **condición** de un `while` **evalúe** tres variables?*"

La respuesta es la que ha dado [eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/329920/2742): crea una [expresión booleana](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81lgebra_de_Boole) que contenga todas las variables que quieras evaluar.

Pero yo no te voy a dar esa respuesta, tu código no necesita un `while` con tres variables, necesita un `for` con una sola:

```
int main(void) {

    for (int delay = 0; delay != 8; ++delay)
        __delay_ms(delay);

    return 0;
}
```

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

Las únicas firmas aceptadas para la función `main` son `int main(void)` o `int main(int, char **)`, en ambos casos debes devolver un entero.

La expresión `A == B` es una **comparación** y no modifica los operandos, así que no hacen nada ninguna de las expresiones `RB0==X;` que tienes en tu bucle.